# If we have a uniform prior probability distribution across all ranges of $ \theta $, does maximum a posteriori become maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

While I am studying maximum a posteriori, somehow it just came across my mind that if I have a uniform prior probability distribution, MAP looks like MLE, am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short yes, a one-liner goes like this

$$h_{MAP} = argmax_{h}\ log(p(D|h) + log(p(h)) = argmax_h\ log(p(D|h)) = h_{MLE} $$

Since $log(p(h))$ under uniform prior is constant. What is more, given enough data, it is true that regardles of prior

$$h_{MAP} \underset{|D| \to \infty}\longrightarrow h_{MLE}$$

A general argument is that $p(D|H)$ depends exponentially on $|D|$ and prior probability $p(h)$ stays constant

Comment: You are saying that MAP becomes MLE when the data size becomes huge, almost infinity? I don't think the size has to be infinite, I think you are  saying when we have a reasonably large size, MAP approaches MLE. Am I right?

Comment: @user122358 I simply say that MAP converges to MLE

Comment: @user122358 for extended discussion of this see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200982/do-bayesian-priors-become-irrelevant-with-large-sample-size/201059#201059