# Using prior knowledge about correlated variable in ridge regression

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, prior, ridge-regression, sparse

I am wondering what methods are available for incorporating prior knowledge of some variable that is correlated with the unknown regression coefficients in a ridge regression. I have a sparse matrix with a high level of multicollinearity. I have knowledge of variable which is correlated to my coefficients. However, the known variable ranges strictly 0-8 while the coefficients can vary from around -10 to 10 (without strict bounds). How can this known variable be incorporated into the regression?

I am currently using scikit-learn RidgeCV in Python for the analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include prior information into your model, using [bayesian](/questions/tagged/bayesian) model is the standard way to go. In Bayesian setting, [ridge regression is equivalent to using Normal priors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328342/is-bayesian-ridge-regression-another-name-of-bayesian-linear-regression/328345#328345). In [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252577/bayes-regression-how-is-it-done-in-comparison-to-standard-regression/252608#252608) you can find an introduction to Bayesian linear regression. As about priors, using $\mathcal{N}(0, 10)$ prior for the parameters is equivalent to imposing your prior knowledge. On another hand, if you knew that the bounds are hard, i.e. parameters cannot go beyond them, you'd use a bounded prior, e.g. truncated normal distribution. Be warned however that the Bayesian formulation of ridge regression does not behave exactly the same, [there were studies](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/431890/shrinkage-priors/431914#431914) showing that using stronger priors may be needed to achieve the regularization effect.