# Bayesian inference with simple models and many data points: impact of priors and the number of data points

Tags: time-series, bayesian, bias, prior, misspecification

**The setting.** Let us assume I would like to perform Bayesian inference for a low-dimensional model on a large dataset, i.e., there are many more data points than there are parameters to identify. Let us moreover assume - as is always the case in practice - that the model is imperfect: it does not describe reality exactly.

**The outcome.** It is known that for many data points, [the evidence introduced by the data often largely outweighs the influence of the prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/200982/131402). The posterior of the parameters will become more and more narrow with a growing number of data points, *even if the model may not fit the data very well and no new information is gained from these new datapoints!*

**Example.** We want to estimate the parameters $a$ and $b$ in the linear model
$$
y = ax + b,
$$
with priors $p(a)$ and $p(b)$ given, where $x(k)$ and $y(k)$ are discrete-time measurements of two slowly time-varying processes. $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are approximately, but not exactly, related by the linear model given above: In "reality",
$$
y = ax + b + c \cdot\sin(\omega t),
$$
where the term $c\cdot\sin(\omega t)$ is not included in the regression model above and hence represents the model error / misspecification in this example.

Consider the following two test cases with different sampling rates ($f_2=10f_1$):
[image]
The parameter estimates for both test cases are almost the same, but the estimated variances in case 2 are about one third of the variances in case 1. (Code + detailed results below).

**Question.** Intuitively, I would expect a "reasonable inference procedure" to yield the same result for both settings, including the variances: Essentially, no new information relevant to the given, low-dimensional model is gained from the additional samples in case 2. While I technically understand how it happens, this influence of the sampling rate / number of samples on the inference result appears undesired / defective. How can I fix this? To me, this appears to be an artifact of the inference procedure assuming the model to be perfect. Can I include some kind of "model uncertainty prior" to make the inference yield the same result in both cases, "recognizing" that no new information is gained?

**Details on the example (Matlab).**

```
t1 = 0:.01:2*pi; t2 = 0:.001:2*pi;
x = @(t) sin(t) + 0.1*t;
y = @(x, t) x + 0.1 + sin(10*t);
x1 = x(t1); x2 = x(t2);
y1 = y(x1, t1); y2 = y(x2, t2);

subplot(2, 2, 1);
scatter(t1, x1);
xlabel('t1'); ylabel('x1');
subplot(2, 2, 2);
scatter(t1, y1);
xlabel('t1'); ylabel('y1');
subplot(2, 2, 3);
scatter(t2, x2);
xlabel('t2'); ylabel('x2');
subplot(2, 2, 4);
scatter(t2, y2);
xlabel('t2'); ylabel('y2');

n_params = 1;
prior = bayeslm(n_params, 'ModelType', 'conjugate', 'Mu', [0, 0.5], 'V', eye(2));
prior.A = 0.001; prior.B = 0.001;
posterior1 = estimate(prior, x1', y1');
posterior2 = estimate(prior, x2', y2');
```

Outputs:

```
Method: Analytic posterior distributions
Number of observations: 629
Number of predictors:   2
Log marginal likelihood: -1316.96

           |  Mean     Std         CI95        Positive        Distribution       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Intercept | 0.1099  0.0871  [-0.061,  0.281]    0.897   t (0.11, 0.09^2,6.3e+02) 
 Beta      | 0.9679  0.1325  [ 0.708,  1.228]    1.000   t (0.97, 0.13^2,6.3e+02) 
 Sigma2    | 3.6909  0.2088  [ 3.304,  4.122]    1.000   IG(314.50, 0.00086)      


Method: Analytic posterior distributions
Number of observations: 6284
Number of predictors:   2
Log marginal likelihood: -8303.38

           |  Mean     Std         CI95        Positive        Distribution       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Intercept | 0.1095  0.0130  [ 0.084,  0.135]    1.000   t (0.11, 0.01^2,6.3e+03) 
 Beta      | 0.9698  0.0198  [ 0.931,  1.009]    1.000   t (0.97, 0.02^2,6.3e+03) 
 Sigma2    | 0.8182  0.0146  [ 0.790,  0.847]    1.000   IG(3142.00, 0.00039)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that linear models assume each data point is independent (i.i.d), while in your example data points are not independent --  they are drawn serially from the same underlying process. A plot of the residuals vs t1 or t2 will reveal a distinct autocorrelated pattern, which is a clear giveaway for this phenomenon.

You've provided an excellent example of how such non-independence can affect standard errors while generating unbiased coefficient estimates. In effect you are 'fooling' the model into thinking it has more independent information than it does. It is generally a huge problem for timeseries and spatial regression models where data are inherently autocorrelated.

The reduction in standard error by 1/3 with a 10-fold increase in sampling makes perfect sense since S.E. scales with 1/sqrt(n).

As for remediation, a common technique is to model the autocorellation-generating process directly, either as a predictor or in the error term. [Gaussian process](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gaussian-process-regression-models.html), [ARIMA](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.estimate.html) and [spatial error](https://methods.sagepub.com/book/spatial-regression-models/n3.xml) models are some examples.

Comment: Ahh yes, of course, you're right! Thanks a lot for the late answer!